# Writing from middle of the page, upside down and from the right hand side?

Tags: graphics, rotating, geometry

How do I start writing from middle of the page, upside down and from the right hand side?

I would like to write from the middle of a page in two directions. The A4 paper will be folded at three places to produce something that looks like a triangle from the side. Here is an attempt to show what I want to accomplish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

    Section 1.\\
    .............................\\
    \rotatebox{180}{Section 2. Upside down text.}\\
    ...(this is the middle of the page)...\\
    Section 3. Text.\\
    .............................\\
    Section 4.

\end{document}
```

Section 1 and 4 will be overlapping and form the base of the triangle. I want the text to be readable from both sides, that's why I rotate the text in section 2. The dots are not needed, they are just showing where the folding will be.

[image]

Comment: it's not clear what do you want, can you add a picture?

Comment: @touhami: Picture added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any package that is designed to typeset text on pages which are intended to be folded; however, [Ti*k*Z](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) can place text at arbitrary position on pages and rotate them (among *many* other things it can do).

Does something like the following work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    remember picture, 
    overlay,
    every node/.style={
      align=justify,
      text width=19cm,
    },
  ]
  \coordinate (first third west) 
              at ($(current page.north west)!0.33!(current page.south west)$);
  \coordinate (first third east) 
              at ($(current page.north east)!0.33!(current page.south east)$);
  \coordinate (second third west) 
              at ($(current page.north west)!0.67!(current page.south west)$);
  \coordinate (second third east) 
              at ($(current page.north east)!0.67!(current page.south east)$);

  \draw [dashed, opacity=0.2] (first third west) -- (first third east);
  \draw [dashed, opacity=0.2] (second third west) -- (second third east);

  \node [anchor=north west] 
        at ($(current page.north west) + (1cm, -1cm)$) 
        {\lipsum[1-2]};

  \node [anchor=north west, rotate=180] 
        at ($(second third east) + (-1cm, 1cm)$) 
        {\lipsum[1-2]};

  \node [anchor=north west] 
        at ($(second third west) + (1cm, -1cm)$) 
        {\lipsum[1-2]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This looks very close to what I want to achieve. I will try to adapt the code a bit.

Comment: I tweaked it a little and added a fourth section and used values 0.25, 0.50 and 0.75. \coordinate (first fourth west) at ($(current page.north west)!0.25!(current page.south west)$); and so on.